# A simple binary addition program I wrote creates a weird buzzing noise through the headphone jack

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

A simple program for adding increasing a binary number by one, converting it to hexadecimal and the `chr()` equivalent starts to make a weird buzzing noise through the headphone jack with each loop. Sort of like a tapping noise I guess

Here is the code I wrote in Python 3:

```
mem = '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000' # Starts at 32

def incbin():
    global mem
    membin = int(mem.replace('b', ''), 2)
    membin += 1
    membinfin = bin(membin)
    mem = membinfin[2:]

while True:
    print('')
    incbin()
    for x in range(int(len(mem)/8)):
        print(hex(int(mem[x:x+8], 2))[2:].zfill(2), end = ' ')
    for x in range(int(len(mem)/8)):
        print(chr(int(mem[x:x+8], 2)), end = ' ')
```

I should also mention that the Windows error sound keeps playing for a split second every now and then but no error appearing.

Here is an example of the console output:

`dc b8 Ü ¸` as you can see, the first 2 sets of characters are the hexadecimal representation and the second set is the `chr()` equivalent.

Could this be a hardware issue? I'm using a Lenovo Yoga 11e with 4GB of RAM and an Intel Core i3 2.3GHz

I don't know why this is happening. I just want to find out why it's happening. I should also say that the fans kick on to the maximum. Which is strange because I can run somewhat graphical intensive games with the fans still quiet.

Comment: Do you hate your pc? [Sisyphean task](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Sisyphean+task) - Maybe write sensible code that does not use a neverending `white(true)`? Maybe do not print every line seperately but instead fill a list and print it once at the end? both would reduce the strain on your PC :o) printing to console is really ssssllooooooooooowwwwww.

Comment: the first usage of `incbin()` will shorten your `mem` to: '100001' - the rest of your code is confusing. What do you want to achieve? what is the goal? getting some kind of 2-hex-space-2hex repersentation of mem with the according chr() for it?

Comment: It seems this may be more of an hardware issue, so Stack Overflow isn't the right place. Check if this happens on other devices, possibly run the code on an online editor. It could be your device, as other operating systems may not produce the sound.

Comment: I don't know about buzzing noise, but this sounds like it should instead be bleeping noise, not buzzing noise... `print("\a")` `\a` is a "bell" control character that should make your computer bleep for a short moment, the sound literally sounds like something you'd hear if you tried to listen to `E` in morses code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could be printing the audible bell character. Do you get the same noise when you do something like `print chr(7)`? How does that compare to the result of `print chr(7) * 100`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
mem = '00100000'

def incbin():
    global mem
    membin = int(mem.replace('b', ''), 2)
    membin += 1
    membinfin = bin(membin)
    mem = membinfin[2:]

def tryChr(number):
    try:
        return f"  {chr(number)}"
    except:
        return  "   N/A"

def formatOne(number):
    h = ( "00" + hex(number)[2:] )[-4:]  # fits with 2**15 max
    return " ".join( (h[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(h),2)) ) + tryChr(number)

l = []
for c in range(32,2**15): # 2**16 gives error - check yourself why
    l.append( formatOne(c) )

print(" ".join( ( l)))
```

It only prints once and stores stuff inlists in between - no endless loop. It should be easier on your hardware and might minimize your problem.